# Rails nesting params in controller create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a rails project and I am trying to add a new model, user_information and link it to a user model.

When trying to set up the create function in the user_controller, I'm struggling with how I can add the information from user_information and pass it as a parameter within the user object.

Any advice on nesting these parameters would be very helpful

Comment: You should look for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Refer:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for nested attributes (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms).

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :user_information

   accepts_nested_parameters_for :user_information

class UserInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
```

Now you can pass nested parameters to create child associations in one step:

```
User.create(email: "<email>", user_information_attributes: { name: "john", etc.. })
```

(Note the `_attributes` suffix)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for nested attributes.
You should take a look at

[gorails](https://gorails.com/episodes/forum-nested-attributes-and-fields-for)

[nested forms and rails 4](https://coderwall.com/p/qwx3qa/nested-form-and-rails-4)